# how to read value of hidden field from page source

Tags: response, inputstream, bufferedreader, hidden-field

I want to retrieve value of a hidden filed which changes with every request send to server. For e.g when i first access the page the `sessid=90334` and at the next page its like `sessid=78204`. The pagesource contains a tag like this `<input type="hidden" name="sessid" value="69529">`. I know how to read the response. I am currently using following code to read the response

```
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
```

Please tell me how can i read the changed value with each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing asp.net application (you haven't specified MVC or asp.net), and you want to access to a hiddenfield value on server side, you should to use runat="server" attribute. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" name="sessid" value="69529">
```

or you can use:

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" id="sessid" value="69529">
```

on server side:

```
var x = sessid.Value
```

Comment: i am not developing asp.net application. I am creating a java application which log in to some other site which require this kind to `sessid` to be provided as a parameter like this `www.example.com/abc.php?sessid=08776`